# Нужна ли запятая перед «и»?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, и

Нужна ли запятая перед «и» в этом предложении?

**Хорошие субтитры и с озвучкой совпадают.**

Comment: А можно контекст увидеть? Если сиысл фразы в том, что хорошие субтиры совпадают с озвучкой (типа "хорошему танцору и ноги не мешают"), то "и" - усилительная частица, запятой заведомо не нужно. А вот  если имеет место констатация факта что некоторые субтитры хорошие, да еще и с озвучкой совпадают, то запятая возможна - как минимум интонационная.

Comment: Контекста не знаю. Сама пыталась ответить на заданный вопрос (это не мой вопрос, просто заинтересовалась, т.к.  рассуждала так же, как и Вы.) Спасибо за ответ!

Comment: Да? Тогда я ответом сделаю. Чтобы было что обсудить.

Comment: Я набросал ответ с листа, позже уточню и исправлю ошибки, если потребуется. Сейчас не имею возможности.

Answer (score 1):

Без контекста тут может быть двоякое понимание.

Если смысл фразы в том, что хорошие субтитры совпадают с озвучкой (типа "хорошему танцору и ноги не мешают"), то "и" - усилительная частица, запятой заведомо не нужно.

А вот если имеет место констатация того факта, что некоторые субтитры хорошие, да еще и с озвучкой совпадают, то запятая возможна. Интонационная - как минимум. Вопрос скорее в том, можно ли в этом втором случае обойтись без запятой. И я не уверен, что можно.
Тут вернее всего (в этом втором случае) два предложения, первое - номинативное, называет объект, второе "и с озвучкой совпадает" - двусоставное, с опущенным подлежащим. "Субтитры" относятся к первому предложению и не могут рассматриваться в качестве подлежащего для второго. Тогда всё предложение надо трактовать как сложносочиненное, без общих членов. Получается, без запятой тут не обойтись.

Ответ: запятая ставится в зависимости от вкладываемого автором (говорящим) смысла. Если подразумевается, что хорошие субтитры должны совпадать с озвучкой, то запятая не нужна. Иначе - возможна, но, видимо, не обязательна, поскольку в этом случае все равно остается неоднозначность. Если "хорошие" - предикативное сказуемое (в значении "субтитры хороши"), то имеем два однородных сказуемых, запятая опять-таки не требуется. И лишь в случае, когда первая часть - номинативное предложение, без запятой, видимо, не обойтись.

Comment: Спасибо! Я тоже думала, что без контекста невозможно точно определить постановку запятой.

Answer (score 0):

Независимо оттого «и» союз или усилительная частица, запятая не нужна.

1. Если «и» — союз:

> **Предложение с однородными сказуемыми, которые образуют сочинительную
> связь, не являются сложными.**
>
> Например: *Жара и усталость взяли, однако ж, свое, и я заснул мертвым
> сном* (две основы, сложносочиненное предложение). *Огромная и
> ослепительно яркая луна стояла уже над горою и ясным зеленоватым
> светом заливала город* (одна основа – подлежащее и два относящихся к
> нему сказуемых, простое предложение).
> [[videotutor-rusyaz.ru](https://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/315-zapyatayaperedsyuzomi.html)]

Тут одно подлежащее «субтитры» и два сказуемых: «[есть] хорошие» и «совпадают».

2. Если «и» — усилительная частица, запятая тоже не ставиться.

> 2. **Соответствует по значению частицам: тоже, также.** *Будет и на нашей улице праздник.* Поговорка. *[Сальери:] Все говорят: нет правды на
>    земле. Но правды нет — и выше.* Пушкин, Моцарт и Сальери. *[Чичиков]
>    заглянул и в городской сад.* Гоголь, Мертвые души. [Словарь русского языка Евгеньевой]